# vim pastes onto completely wrong location

Tags: vim, paste

This has not just once, but happened many times. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.. it tends to occur more frequently during remote control. I would set the mouse cursor at a certain position where I would paste, then it either goes to somewhere really far down or somewhere up.. until after meaningless trial/error(of which pattern I do not understand) it will at one point find where I'm looking for.

Does anyone know why this is so? As I tried to recreate for capturing of screenshots, it now works fine, again with no logic -_-

Comment: What does `:set mouse?` output?

Comment: oh i think this may work. can I also ask why the format becomes unstructured when I paste texts that are originally formatted nicely?

Comment: Because Vim tries to indent the pasted text. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/620980/remove-vim-indents-when-i-paste-directly-from-system-clipboard

Comment: no.this is madness..:set mouse did not stop it from starting with checking many places to paste

Comment: I didn't ask you to run `:set mouse`. I asked what the output of `:set mouse?` is.

Comment: gives nothing but `mouse =`

Comment: VIM is not supposed to be used with mouse :)   but if you use it you have to set it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens to me from time to time, when I copy a .vimrc from a regular desktop to a machine I use only through SSH or other remote session. I normaly use `set mouse=a` via .vimrc. On remote machines this breaks also depending on the version of Vim. Pasting with middle mouse scrolls up or down a few lines and drops the clipboard content in that new location instead of Vim-cursor position.

I fix this by simply removing the `set mouse=a` it pastes as expected but does not disable mouse navigation. To unset mouse use `set mouse=`.

For some versions of Vim this was also fixed by scrolling a few lines up and down with the mouse.

Nevertheless I admire the work of art of so many that makes it possible to translate my local pointer device actions into terminal commands understood by a program far far away and not destroying the universe.